# How to I turn off the ambient light in Scene Kit (with Swift)?

Tags: swift, scenekit

When I create a new Scene Kit Game using the Swift language, there is already some come which gives this result :
[image]
**I want to turn off the ambient light which is lighting the cube but I don't get how to do that since there isn't any light explicitly attached to any node.**

Her's the Game View Controller code :

```
import SceneKit
import QuartzCore

class GameViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var gameView: GameView

    override func awakeFromNib(){
        // create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene()

        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 2)

        // create and add a 3d box to the scene
        let boxNode = SCNNode()
        boxNode.geometry = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0.02)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

        // create and configure a material
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = NSImage(named: "texture")
        material.specular.contents = NSColor.whiteColor()
        material.specular.intensity = 0.2
        material.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

        // set the material to the 3d object geometry
        boxNode.geometry.firstMaterial = material

        // animate the 3d object
        let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
        animation.toValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 1, z: 0, w: M_PI*2))
        animation.duration = 5
        animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT //repeat forever
        boxNode.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "")

        // set the scene to the view
        self.gameView!.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        self.gameView!.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        self.gameView!.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        self.gameView!.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor()
    }

}
```

Comment: I've ported your code to ObjC and replaced in the iOS SceneKit template, I just changed NSImage and NSColor to UIImage and UIColor, and the cube is rendered, but there is no texture nor lights, do you have an Idea what the problem could be? I guess the code is loading the default texture in the template. Do I need to add a light to your code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you are seeing the "default" lighting.

You can explicitly disable it by calling

```
gameView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = false
```

It will also be disables as soon as you add your own lights to the scene.

Comment: This can also be turned off from the SCNView inspector in the StoryBoard

Comment: I don’t think it disables as more lights are added. What kind of lights disable it?