# SceneKit – Why does adding spot light blacken the floor?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, virtual-reality

Screenshot #1 shows a simple SceneKit scene with only an ambient light (explicitly added, not the default one).

Screenshot #2 shows what happens after adding a spot light. The whole floor turns black. This spot light has the default properties after adding a spot light within the SceneKit Editor.

This also happens with a directional light.

To be clear, it is understood that the scene contains ambient lighting by default. However, we explicitly added an ambient light (and even tested with two) *before* adding the spot/directional light. So the default light theory mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697574/how-to-i-turn-off-the-ambient-light-in-scene-kit-with-swift) no longer apply. Hence the confusion.

Spot lights and directional lights are supposed to add light to a particular region of the scene, that is understood. But they shouldn't blacken areas outside their scope, right?

New to 3D graphics and SceneKit so any advice is very much appreciated.

**Screenshot #1:**
[image]

**Screenshot #2:**
[image]

Comment: It's the default lighting when you have no lights of your own. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697574/how-to-i-turn-off-the-ambient-light-in-scene-kit-with-swift You should add your own omnidirectional light.

Comment: @JamesP what wasn't clear in screenshot 1 is there is already an ambient light explicitly added, hence the confusion. so adding a spotlight effectively "reduces" light instead of adds it. you can test this for yourself. add an ambient light (or even two) then a spotlight.

Comment: You're right, it seems like there's still default lighting going on until you add another type of light source. I found this post that seems to explain it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705733/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-dark-low-light-scenekit-scene

Answer (score 6):

### What's the issue

> An empty SceneKit's scene (without any added light) has a **default omnidirectional light** that you can easily turn on or off:

```
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
```

Let's see what Apple documentation says about it:

> If this property’s value is **false** (the default), the only light sources SceneKit uses for rendering a scene are those contained in the scene graph. If you change the value to **true**, SceneKit automatically adds and places an omnidirectional light source when rendering scenes that c**ontain no lights or only contain ambient lights**.

**When you add lights to your scene they behave correspondingly. The main principles are**:

- If a new light is added, default SceneKit's light turns off.
- If light's **`rays are parallel to any 3D surface`** that surface will be black.

  - This behavior is true for **Directional Light** or **Spot Light** with a narrow light-cone.
  - That occurs because SceneKit has no [Global Illumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_illumination) option (or secondary light rays).
- **Ambient light** is omnidirectional and **has NO decay**. It has only shading for surface normals.
- **Point light** is omnidirectional and has a decay (light loses its intensity depending on distance).

**That's why floor in your scene turned black**.

And remember – you can easily turn any light on or off:

```
@IBAction func turnLight(_ sender: NSButton) {   

    if counter % 2 == 0 {
        ambientLightNode.isHidden = true
    } else {
        ambientLightNode.isHidden = false
    }
    counter += 1
}
```

### Solution

When you're lighting your scene you need to use several light types. If you use just Directional Light, some objects' surfaces in your scene will be black, so use additional Ambient Light with low intensity – 200 to 500 lumens – to lighten these black surfaces. Don't use too many Point Lights, because each Point Light is a set of 6 Spot Lights with 90 degree cones. So each Point Light with turned on shadows is computationally intensive!

P.S.

If you're interested in RealityKit lighting, [read my story](https://medium.com/macoclock/realitykit-911-lighting-and-shadows-66f99bcd5219) on Medium.